# Swift: TableViewController not woking with CoreData (NSRangeException when Loading table)

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, core-data

So I was trying out TableViewController and CoreData by making a relatively simple app. All my app does is tell me my credit card balance by adding my transactions up. Also, I'm doing this using two currencies, USD and EGP.

I stored the data permanently before using NSUserDefaults, and it worked. But then I realized that I needed to change to CoreData if I want to make a custom class that stores a lot of details about a transaction (Title, Amount, isEGP...) Also I'm planning on adding date.

Anyway. So I decided to try out CoreData using [this](http://www.raywenderlich.com/115695/getting-started-with-core-data-tutorial) RayWenderlich tutorial. I finished everything and when I ran it, it added one element correctly! But when I add another, it crashes with NSRangeException: "1 is out of Range for Bounds[0...0]" I'm modeling my data using a static array of type [NSManagedObject] for all the transactions. The problem seems to have to do with the fact that I'm using a TableViewController not a TableView (i'm guessing) since in the class file here:

```
class TransactionsTableViewController: UITableViewController {


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
            print (LockScreenViewController.transactions.count)
            return LockScreenViewController.transactions.count
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = UITableViewCell (style: UITableViewCellStyle.Default, reuseIdentifier: "Cell");

        let transaction = LockScreenViewController.transactions[indexPath.row]

        let title = transaction.valueForKey("title") as! String
        let amount = transaction.valueForKey("amount") as! Double
        let isEGP = transaction.valueForKey("isEGP") as! Bool

        cell.textLabel!.text = isEGP ?
            (title + ":        " + String(amount) + " EGP") :
                (title + ":        $" + String(amount))

        return cell;
    }

}
```

it prints out the count once, and then crashes...instead of 3 or 4 times when there is only 1 element (or no elements). I have no idea how to fix it.

When a button is pressed, I call this function to save the transaction to my array:

```
func saveTransaction(title: String, amount: Double, isEGP: Bool) {

    //1 Managed Context
    let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
    let managedContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext

    //2
    let entity = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Transaction", inManagedObjectContext: managedContext)

    let transaction = NSManagedObject(entity: entity!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: managedContext)
    //3
    transaction.setValue(title, forKey:  "title");
    transaction.setValue(amount, forKey: "amount");
    transaction.setValue(isEGP, forKey: "isEGP");

    //4
    do {
        try managedContext.save()
        //5
        LockScreenViewController.transactions.append(transaction)
    } catch let error as NSError  {
        print("Could not save \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
    }
}
```

The rest of the code should be fine, but if none of the past code seems to have anything wrong with it, the problem may be because I added a CoreData file *after* I created the project, instead of checking the "Use Core Data" Button in the beginning. (I fixed the AppDelegate manually, so I don't think that's the issue)

In any case, here is my project file:

http://dropcanvas.com/ogcfo

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Core Data + `UITableView` = `NSFetchedResultsController`!

You should be using an `NSFetchedResultsController`. The easiest way to get started is to examine the Xcode template for "Master-Detail" where a table view with a fetched results controller is implemented in the master controller.

Note how the `NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate` helps you update the table view dynamically without much effort.

This is by far the most robust solution, plus you get incredible scalability and optimizations.

Comment: Sorry you elaborate more... why is it NSFetchedResultsConrtoller?

Comment: The reason is in the last sentence of my answer.